# Collecting Messages with specific Keywords on Tele Bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a bot on Telegram itself that will collect messages specific keywords from various channels I'm part of, on my bot. Is there a way I can pull this off?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Bot can be only admin in a channel, in this case message updates are mostly like ones from users. But I suppose you don't have admin rights for a bot in all the channels.

If so, a bot can't get messages from a channel. You should look forward connecting to telegram with an account, not a bot. You can use tdlib for it (imho the best option, for any language, there are many wrappers and libraries) or pyrogram/telethon in python

Comment: Thanks bud for the reply, yea what you said sounds about right. That being said, how can I use my current telegram account as this message aggregator from various groups that will only show messages with specific keywords because I can read message from one group at a time. It'd really kind if you could share some kinda guide that can help me pull this off.

Comment: Cuz you see I get ton of messages from loads of channels on my tele everyday but only very few are relevant to me with distinct keyword. So what I'm trying to achieve is to push all such messages on some kinda page I can view em. Hopefully, that doesn't make you wanna scratch head 